# Objective-C AES key length how to fixing 16 bytes

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, aes

I'm new on objective-c and aes encryption.

I'm working with AES encrypt and decrypt data on different platforms(ios,android,c#).On Java and C# codes creating new key for different situations and I using that keys just first 16bytes.

Like this:

**Java:**

```
private static byte[] getKeyBytes(String key) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];
    byte[] parameterKeyBytes = key.getBytes(characterEncoding);
    System.arraycopy(parameterKeyBytes, 0, keyBytes, 0, 
    Math.min(parameterKeyBytes.length, keyBytes.length));
    return keyBytes;
}
```

**C#:**

```
 public static RijndaelManaged GetRijndaelManaged(String secretKey)
    {
        var keyBytes = new byte[16];
        var secretKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey);
        Array.Copy(secretKeyBytes, keyBytes, Math.Min(keyBytes.Length, secretKeyBytes.Length));
        return new RijndaelManaged
        {
            Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
            Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
            KeySize = 128,
            BlockSize = 128,
            Key = keyBytes,
            IV = ivBytes
        };
    }
```

These clearly works. 
In obj-c, when key size smaller than 16 character, encryption mostly worked correct. But key is if so bigger than 16 character, encryption does not work correctly. How can I fixing key byte size to 16 and use it? or another way?

**Obj-C AES method:**

```
  - (NSData *)AES128Operation:(CCOperation)operation key:(NSString *)key iv:(NSString *)iv
{
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128 + 1];
    memset(keyPtr, 0, sizeof(keyPtr));
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    char ivPtr[kCCBlockSizeAES128 + 1];
    memset(ivPtr, 0, sizeof(ivPtr));
    [iv getCString:ivPtr maxLength:sizeof(ivPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);


    size_t numBytesCrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                                          kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                          kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr,
                                          kCCBlockSizeAES128,
                                          ivPtr,
                                          [self bytes],
                                          dataLength,
                                          buffer,
                                          bufferSize,
                                          &numBytesCrypted);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesCrypted];
    }
    free(buffer);
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AES does not support key sizes less than 16-bytes, it supports exactly three key sizesL 128, 192 & 256 bits. If you use a smaller key the extra bytes have to come from someplace. Some implementations will add null bytes some will just use wherever garbage bytes follow the provided key bytes.

The resolution: always use the correct length key.